# How to use Custom List Column as refiners in Content Search Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part

I am using Content Search Web part in Sharepoint Online Site. The search Query is set to retrive List items for one list only like this: 
`path:"https://XXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/Lists/ListName/" (contentclass:"STS_ListItem") {SearchBoxQuery}`

But in the search results, I am able to display only site columns not list columns. 
The same is with refiner web part where only columns like `Author` and `Modified Date` are availble.

So how to use Custom List Columns in Search results and refiener web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to map the columns to some crawled properties.

if it is a date then use refinabledate00 or any of them that Arent used.
if it is a text field then use refinablestring00 etc.

once you have mapped the columns you have to wait for the SharePoint online to do a full crawl. that usually happens sometimes during the weekend.
After the full crawl has happened you can use your custom columns in refiners.

Comment: What in case of a choice column?

Comment: hm... that is much harder as there is no refinable choice. you could try hacking it a bit. it wont be pretty but you could make a calculated column to read what your choice column has or maybe try a lookup column that stores the value. then you could try mapping either of those.
as i said it wont be pretty and you might not be able to do that at all but it is worth a shot.